# How to display a hyper link in the ANT Console

Tags: ant

I need to show an hyperlink once the ant build is complete, I tried using
echo message"hyperlink" in the build.xml but its getting printed as a string. 
I need to display it as a hyper link

EX:  href="http://srti076a:9000" title="Access the Sonar Report"

Answer (score 1):

This is related to [ant bugId 25540](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25540) which is closed with status RESOLVED WORKSFORME.
The recommended way to echo hyperlinks is to use the [echoxml task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html) which is available since Ant 1.7 :

```
<echoxml>
 <a href="http://srti076a:9000">Access the Sonar Report</a>
</echoxml>
```

Comment: This comes out as a string for me.  I even tried your example in my Ant build, and I received:
    <a href="http://srti076a:9000">Access the Sonar Report</a>

Comment: @Steve I assumed he wants to use xmllogger.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that link be in either your CI server or the notification your CI server sends?